# How do I trigger deploy after the successful build of a specific branch?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins task that triggers on any changes made to a gitlab project.

There are a few situations I'd like to be able to set up, however I'm not sure how to best accomplish them.  Most of it centers around being able to do the following:

- Once the job is complete, I'd like to trigger another job that takes the contents of the first job's workspace (emptying out the initial one).
- I'd like for a way to only run certain other jobs when the workspace contains a specific branch (automatically deploy develop branch to a preview environment).

Comment: Re your second point: Are these other jobs downstream jobs of the one mentioned in your first point? Or are they triggered independently and you'd like to abort them if the specific-branch condition isn't met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"to trigger another job that takes the contents of the first job's workspace"* see [Shared workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin):

> *This plugin allows to share workspaces by Jenkins jobs with the same SCM repos.*